# Сгруппировать строки

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет!

Составил запрос:

```
select ta.id, ct.tag_id
from table_a ta join table_tags ct on ta.id = ct.table_a_id
where ct.tag_id in (1,2,3)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополняю этот запрос строкой **group by cr.id**:

```
select ta.id, ct.tag_id
from table_a ta join table_tags ct on ta.id = ct.table_a_id
where ct.tag_id in (1,2,3)
group by cr.id
```

[image: Результат:]

Как сделать так, чтобы в tag_id второй строки были все три тега в колнке tag_id (1, 2 и 3)? Можно в формате varchar

Я не большой специалист в sql, простите, если вопрос банальный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете базу MySQL, то используйте функцию `group_concat`.

В итоге ваш запрос будет:

```
select ta.id, 
    group_concat(ct.tag_id) as group_tag_id
from table_a ta join table_tags ct on ta.id = ct.table_a_id
where ct.tag_id in (1,2,3)
group by ta.id
```

[Пример на db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qp3NV3YcUj41TKdNSfHLQR/0)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: @KonstantinSkokov не забудьте отметить вопрос как правильный галочкой :) это поможет дальнейшим участникам, а также ruSO не будет поднимать вопрос как неотвеченный.